# userAgent check to see Mobile or Web

Tags: apex, mobile

I'm using something similar to the following code in the Apex controller to check if the user is accessing website or mobile.

Following code I'm using:

```
userAgent.contains('iPhone') 
   || ( userAgent.contains('Android') 
   || userAgent.contains('Mobile'));
```

but instead I'm looking to have generic value to check all mobile device instead of keep adding?

for an example I may end up adding `Windows device` then I have to go and change the code which I would like to avoid changing for every single mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Spring '16, you have the ability to check the UITheme used by the current user by using

```
UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed()
// or
UserInfo.getUiTheme()
```

So you can have a Boolean to use it back into your VFPage or Component or whatever your Apex Controller is linked to :

```
// Controller
Boolean isMobile { get; set; }
public whateverConstructor(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    isMobile = UserInfo.getUiTheme() == 'Theme4t';
}

// VFPage
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!isMobile}">
blah
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Don't forget to check for `sforce.one` presence to double ensure the user is on a mobile ;)

Source : https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_vf_uitheme.htm

Answer (score -1):

This [Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) web site includes regular expressions like (this one in JavaScript):

> (function(a,b){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge
>   |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm(
>   os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows
>   ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a
>   wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|-m|r
>   |s
>   )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw-(n|u)|c55/|capi|ccwa|cdm-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(-|*)|g1
>   u|g560|gene|gf-5|g-mo|go(.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd-(m|p|t)|hei-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(
>   i|ip)|hs-c|ht(c(-|
>   |*|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(
>   |-|/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(
>   |/)|klon|kpt |kwc-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(
>   g|/(k|l|u)|50|54|-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1-w|m3ga|m50/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(-|
>   |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v
>   )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt-g|qa-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|-[2-7]|i-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h-|oo|p-)|sdk/|se(c(-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh-|shar|sie(-|m)|sk-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h-|v-|v
>   )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl-|tdg-|tel(i|m)|tim-|t-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m-|m3|m5)|tx-9|up(.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(-|
>   )|webc|whit|wi(g
>   |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas-|your|zeto|zte-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))window.location=b})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera,'http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');

so it looks like there isn't a simple answer. Note that the site says that the regular expression was last updated 1 August 2014 so it looks like the author may have given up trying to track all the possible user agents.

CSS frameworks such as Bootstrap bases their layout on the screen width using CSS expressions such as:

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    /* ... */
}
```

See e.g. [Get the device width in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850164/get-the-device-width-in-javascript). This looks like the better way to go.