# How To Get URL Into Controller On Mobile

Tags: visualforce, mobile, parameters

H**ow do I get the URL (specifically the parameters) into my Controller from a VF Page when the device is a mobile phone?** The VF Page is housed on a Community Page. I can get the URL param just fine when on Desktop using: ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('referer'); But when I am using mobile (when UserInfo.getUiTheme() == 'Theme4t'), then this value is null.

I have attempted all of these on my mobile device and **NONE** work...
[image: failed mobile attempts]

The following solution only works for desktop with 1 parameter:
ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('referer').substringAfter('?param=');

But I really need this to work for a mobile device.

**Any suggestions?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Resolution:** To my understanding this is **NOT** possible to get the URL param into the Controller of a VF Page embedded in a Community Page while User is on a Mobile device.

To know if the User is on Desktop or Mobile I found [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140233/useragent-check-to-see-mobile-or-web) question which was useful ([more info](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_vf_uitheme.htm)). I found someone else had [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IFD4QAO) issue with Salesforce1. Another [question](https://www.forcetalks.com/salesforce-topic/is-it-at-all-possible-to-pass-a-parameter-through-a-url-to-an-input-field-on-a-visualforce-page/), but not Mobile related. I did the following that [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296876/visualforce-page-on-android) link suggested, but still no resolution (hence my initial screenshot testing all sorts of ways to get this value...).

I hope someone can prove me wrong though and give insight on how to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get URL parameters, doesn't this work?

```
String param = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('param');
```

Comment: This method does not actually work from inside a Community, both Desktop and Mobile (both android and ios) it seems this method is not available. The line you suggested returns NULL. I also tried to put mobile in 'desktop mode', but that didn't seem to work either. Thanks again for your response, any other suggestions? I'm beginning to think this is absolutely impossible to get a URL param value on Mobile. Desktop >> String param = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('referer').substringAfter('?param='); This is a null pointer exception on Mobile because 'referer' is not a header value.